# The callback has been called, but $broadcast has not?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

This is my spec file, and I can't get it to work properly.

The service's `execute()` method does some AJAX request. In case of receiving `401 Unauthorized` it should broadcast `evt-unauthorized` on `$rootScope`.

While testing, I've noticed strange thing: `.$broadcast` seems to never have been called. 
If I add a spy callback though, Jasmine tells that the callback actually has been called, while `.$broadcast` is still untouched.

Am I missing something?

```
'use strict';

describe('Service: Some_Service', function () {
    var service, http_backend, rootScope;

    beforeEach(module('Some_Module'));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($httpBackend, $rootScope, Some_Service) {
        http_backend = $httpBackend;
        rootScope = $rootScope.$new();
        service = Some_Service;
        http_backend.whenPOST('http://api.site.com/restricted/area').respond(401);
    }));

    it('should broadcast `evt-unauthorized` on root scope in case of 401', function () {
        var done = false;
        var promise;

        var callback = jasmine.createSpy('callback');
        spyOn(rootScope, '$broadcast');
        rootScope.$on('evt-unauthorized', callback);

        runs(function() {
            promise = service.execute();
            expect(promise).toBeTruthy();
            promise.error(function() {
                done = true;
                //this test succeeds
                expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalled();
                //this one fails
                expect(rootScope.$broadcast).toHaveBeenCalled();
            });
            http_backend.flush();
        });

        waitsFor(function() {
            return done;
        }, 1000);
    });

    afterEach (function () {
        http_backend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation ();
        http_backend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest ();
    });
});
```

Comment: Should it broadcast on the actual root scope (`$rootScope`), or on the child scope of the $rootScope that you named `rootScope`, but which is not the root scope? I expect it boradcasts on $rootScope, since it doesn't have access to the child scope you create in your test.

Comment: @JBNizet, oh, you're right. That's what happens, when you copy/paste things around. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service receives the "real" `$rootScope` through the `inject` function whereas you watch on `rootScope`, which is only a childscope of $rootScope.

You'll have to spy on the $rootScope's $broadcast method:

```
spyOn($rootScope, '$broadcast').andCallThrough();
```